# Scala idiom to find first Some of Option from iterator

Tags: scala, scala-collections, scala-option

I have an iterator of Options, and would like to find the first member that is:

1. Some
2. and meets a predicate

What's the best idiomatic way to do this?

Also: If an exception is thrown along the way, I'd like to ignore it and move on to the next member

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
optionIterator find { case Some(x) if predicate(x) => true  case _ => false }
```

As for ignoring exceptions… Is it the predicate that could `throw`? 'Cause that's not really wise. Nonetheless…

```
optionIterator find {
  case Some(x) => Try(predicate(x)) getOrElse false
  case _       => false
}
```

Comment: Or `Try(p(x)) getOrElse false`.

Answer (score 3):

Adding a coat of best and idiomatic to the paint job:

```
scala> val vs = (0 to 10) map { case 3 => None case i => Some(i) }
vs: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Option[Int]] = Vector(Some(0), Some(1), Some(2), None, Some(4), Some(5), Some(6), Some(7), Some(8), Some(9), Some(10))

scala> def p(i: Int) = if (i % 2 == 0) i > 5 else ???
p: (i: Int)Boolean

scala> import util._
import util._

scala> val it = vs.iterator
it: Iterator[Option[Int]] = non-empty iterator

scala> it collectFirst { case Some(i) if Try(p(i)) getOrElse false => i }
res2: Option[Int] = Some(6)
```

Getting the first even number over five that doesn't blow up the test.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you can wrap your predicate so that any error returns false:

```
iterator.flatMap(x => x).find(yourSafePredicate)
```

`flatMap` takes a collection of collections (which an iterable of `Option` is as `Option` and `Either` are considered collections with a max size of one) and transforms it into a single collection:

```
scala> for { x <- 1 to 3; y <- 1 to x } yield x :: y :: Nil
res30: IndexedSeq[List[Int]] = Vector(List(1, 1), List(2, 1), List(2, 2), List(3, 1), List(3, 2), List(3, 3))

scala> res30.flatMap(x => x)
res31: IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3)
```

`find` returns the first entry in your iterable that matches a predicate as an `Option` or `None` if there is no match:

```
scala> (1 to 10).find(_ > 3)
res0: Option[Int] = Some(4)

scala> (1 to 10).find(_ == 11)
res1: Option[Int] = None
```

Answer (score 1):

Some sample data

```
scala> val l = Seq(Some(1),None,Some(-7),Some(8))
l: Seq[Option[Int]] = List(Some(1), None, Some(-7), Some(8))
```

Using **flatMap** on a Seq of Options will produce a Seq of **defined** values, all the None's will be discarded

```
scala> l.flatMap(a => a)
res0: Seq[Int] = List(1, -7, 8)
```

Then use **find** on the sequence - you will get the first value, that satisfies the predicate. Pay attention, that found value is wrapped as Option, cause **find** should be able to return valid value (None) value in case of "not found" situation.

```
scala> l.flatMap(a => a).find(_ < 0)
res1: Option[Int] = Some(-7)
```

As far as I know it is "OK" way for the Scala.

Might be more idiomatic way is to use **collect** / **collectFirst** on the Seq ...

```
scala> l.collectFirst { case a@Some(x) if x < 0 => a }
res2: Option[Some[Int]] = Some(Some(-7))
```

Pay attention that here we have Some(Some(-7)) because the **collectFind** should have chance to produce "not found" value, so here 1st Some - from collectFirst, the 2nd Some - from the source elements of Seq of Option's.

You can **flatten** the Some(Some(-7)) if you need the values in your hand.

```
scala> l.collectFirst({ case a@Some(x) if x < 0 => a }).flatten
res3: Option[Int] = Some(-7)
```

If nothing found - you will have the None

```
scala> l.collectFirst({ case a@Some(x) if x < -10 => a }).flatten
res9: Option[Int] = None
```

Comment: The question was about iterator.